# create and switch database dynamically via hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc

please consider such a scenario：

        (1)there is one global database A including two tables:Users,Configs.
        (2)Table Users hava  three columns:UserId,UserName,UserPass.
        (3)Table Configs have six columns:Id,UserId,Host,Port,DBUser,DBPass.
        (4)There is another database user_A including many tables.
    When user_A logs in,the application will check user's password via table Users in database,then get user_A's database connection string from table Configs in database A. All the rest operations are based on database User_A.
    in addition,when a user log in,there is no corresponding database,the application should create the corresponding database first.

How do I implement it?I'm using struts2+spring+hibernate.
I would be very grateful for your answer ：）

Comment: You can try hibernate session factory.

Comment: i use hibernate session factory in applicationContext.xml,but the datasource is hardcoded in the xml,of cource i can hardcode more than one datasource in the xml file.but how can i create datasource in memory dynamically using the connection string that stored in database A?

Comment: How about two different SessionFactories?

Comment: Each user will have a database,will this need a lot of SessionFactories? :(

Comment: I would say that having an overhead of a SessionFactory per user is negligible comparing to having a database per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We worked with several datasources in system, however they were hardcoded in XML file. As far as I remember our approach was similar to this:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/93914-dynamic-datasources-at-runtime

I also found this example. Maybe it will help you.

http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/create-drop-databases-dynamically-java-jsp-code

Comment: thank u very much!your first link is much helpful to me!But if i create datasource dynamically,is it possible to use both connection pool at the same time?in the link above ,connection pool is not mentioned.

Comment: I'm glad that link was useful. Do you mean use dynamic DataSources simultaneously?

Comment: yeah,yes!many users will connect to one same dynamic DataSource,can they share a connection pool?

Comment: As I understand, every DataSource creates  it's own ConnectionPool. You can configure it during creation of DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

The database needs to exist when the `SessionFactory` is built. Creating one database per user is a very strange requirement.

You can have one database and multiple user accounts, and using roles and privileges you can restrict user's access.

You could use the Hibernate `ConnectionProvider` to control database connections, but creating a database on-the-fly would require access to the operating system shell.

Comment: thanks for your answer:) I just take it to do an example that per user have a database.  In fact,our application will deal with many partners' project data. every project's data will be stored in its own database.